# Tomar los datos de un hash en RUBY y devolver un string (sin ser array)

Tags: ruby, hash

quisiera preguntarles ¿en qué fallo con la respuesta que doy al ejercicio? Desde ya, muchísimas gracias por leer.

/////Consigna Ejercicio:////// 
necesitamos un mixin Pretty, que provea un método prettify y haga la impresión de los objetos más bonita. Debe poder usarse así:

```
class Coordenada
include Pretty

def initialize
@longitud = 0
@longitud = 0
end

 # nuestro mixin debe utilizar este método
 # para saber qué mostrar
def pretty_attributes
{latitud: @latitud, longitud: @longitud}

end
end

Coordenada.new.prettify
# => "latitud: 0\nlongitud: 0"
```

/////termina consigna/////

Mi solución:

```
module Pretty
def prettify 

pretty_attributes="latitud: #{@latitud}\nlongitud: #{@longitud}"
 end     
end
```

///El Problema -> 
No funciona para

```
 Pretty should eq "foo: 3\nbar: 5\ngoo: 6"
```

Si funciona para

```
 Pretty should eq "latitud: 0\nlongitud: 0"
 Pretty should eq "latitud: 20\nlongitud: 30"
```

Entiendo que esa solución para más de dos variables de atributo no funcionaría, entonces probé otras opciones en dónde se toma el contenido del hash (independientemente de cuál sea), pero no doy con los métodos adecuados.

```
#pretty_attributes="latitud: #{@latitud}\nlongitud: #{@longitud}" 

#h.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} is #{value}" }
#pretty_attributes.map{|*|* = initialize}.join("\n")
#pretty_attributes.take(4).join(" ")
#pretty_attributes.select{|latitud, longitud| latitud = [:latitud] , longitud = [:longitud] }
# { |el| "#{el} not found" }
#"latitud: #{*}\nlongitud: #{*}"
#pretty_attributes.each{|a, b| puts "latitud:         
#{[:latitud]}\nlongitud: #{[:latitud]}"}
#select{|latitud, longitud| latitud == @latitud && longitud == @longitud puts "latitud: #{[latitud]}\nlongitud: #{[latitud]}"}


#each_value{|@latitud, @longitud| puts "latitud: #{[value]}\nlongitud: #{[value]}"}
#pretty_attributes.flatten.join("\n") 
#pretty_attributes.flatten
```

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.
Juan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
module Pretty
  def prettify 
    pretty_attributes.map{|k, v| "#{k}: #{v}" }.join("\n")
  end     
end
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alter Lagos!  al ver el código así, solo me pregunto ¿por qué no lo vi cuando leí (varias veces) la web de teoría en la parte de "map"? ajjajaja. Todavía estoy en una etapa inicial, me pierdo un poco :-) Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @jdipro que bueno que te sirvió, saludos